# is it possible to use FOSCommentBundle without FOSUserBundle?

Tags: symfony, foscommentbundle

i want to know if it is possible to use FOSCommentBundle without using 
FOSUserBundle,
because i am trying to use FOSCommentBundle without FOSUserBundle 

and i followed the 4 steps in the [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)
but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The integration with FOSUserBundle is an "Optional step".

So FOSUserBundle is not required by FOSCommentBundle.